# How do you align text in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do you align all text and bullet points in Microsoft Power point

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything (All)
Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for center,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for right and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for left.